# How to plot a consecutive set of data?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a series of data point:

```
q1 = {{0.0001, 0.762371}, {0.000621053, 0.768171}, {0.00114211, 
 0.773225}, {0.00166316, 0.777677}, {0.00218421, 
 0.781639}, {0.00270526, 0.785196}, {0.00322632, 
 0.788416}, {0.00374737, 0.791351}, {0.00426842, 
 0.794044}, {0.00478947, 0.79653}, {0.00531053, 
 0.798837}, {0.00583158, 0.800987}, {0.00635263, 0.803}, {0.00687368,
 0.804891}, {0.00739474, 0.806675}, {0.00791579, 
 0.808362}, {0.00843684, 0.809962}, {0.00895789, 
 0.811485}, {0.00947895, 0.812936}, {0.01, 0.814322}}
```

q1 =

[image]

```
q2 = {{0.01, 0.814322}, {0.02, 0.833238}, {0.03, 0.844964}, {0.04, 
0.853516}, {0.05, 0.860265}, {0.06, 0.865849}, {0.07, 
0.870619}, {0.08, 0.874787}, {0.09, 0.87849}, {0.1, 
0.881824}, {0.11, 0.884857}, {0.12, 0.887639}, {0.13, 
0.890209}, {0.14, 0.892597}, {0.15, 0.894828}, {0.16, 
0.896919}, {0.17, 0.898886}, {0.18, 0.900745}, {0.19, 
0.902505}, {0.2, 0.904175}, {0.21, 0.905764}, {0.22, 
0.907279}, {0.23, 0.908727}, {0.24, 0.910112}, {0.25, 
0.91144}, {0.26, 0.912714}, {0.27, 0.913939}, {0.28, 
0.915117}, {0.29, 0.916252}, {0.3, 0.917347}, {0.31, 
0.918403}, {0.32, 0.919424}, {0.33, 0.920411}, {0.34, 
0.921367}, {0.35, 0.922292}, {0.36, 0.923189}, {0.37, 
0.924059}, {0.38, 0.924903}, {0.39, 0.925723}, {0.4, 
0.92652}, {0.41, 0.927295}, {0.42, 0.928049}, {0.43, 
0.928783}, {0.44, 0.929498}, {0.45, 0.930194}, {0.46, 
0.930873}, {0.47, 0.931534}, {0.48, 0.93218}, {0.49, 
0.932811}, {0.5, 0.933426}, {0.51, 0.934027}, {0.52, 
0.934615}, {0.53, 0.935188}, {0.54, 0.93575}, {0.55, 0.9363}, {0.56,
0.936837}, {0.57, 0.937363}, {0.58, 0.937878}, {0.59, 
0.938382}, {0.6, 0.938876}, {0.61, 0.93936}, {0.62, 
0.939835}, {0.63, 0.9403}, {0.64, 0.940756}, {0.65, 
0.941204}, {0.66, 0.941642}, {0.67, 0.942073}, {0.68, 
0.942496}, {0.69, 0.94291}, {0.7, 0.943318}, {0.71, 
0.943719}, {0.72, 0.944112}, {0.73, 0.944498}, {0.74, 
0.944878}, {0.75, 0.945251}, {0.76, 0.945618}, {0.77, 
0.945978}, {0.78, 0.946334}, {0.79, 0.946682}, {0.8, 
0.947023}, {0.81, 0.947363}, {0.82, 0.947695}, {0.83, 
0.948023}, {0.84, 0.948345}, {0.85, 0.948662}, {0.86, 
0.948974}, {0.87, 0.949282}, {0.88, 0.949584}, {0.89, 
0.949882}, {0.9, 0.950177}, {0.91, 0.950466}, {0.92, 
0.950751}, {0.93, 0.951032}, {0.94, 0.95131}, {0.95, 
0.951583}, {0.96, 0.951853}, {0.97, 0.952118}, {0.98, 
0.95238}, {0.99, 0.952639}, {1., 0.952894}}
```

q2 =

[image]

When I tried to combine them the result was:

```
p1 = ListPlot[q1, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = ListPlot[q2, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[{p2, p1}]
```

[image]

As you can see the red part which is q1 is not noticeable.

I also tried:

```
q3 = Join[q1, q2, 1];
ListPlot[q3]
```

[image]

I want the graphs q1 and q2 as you can see above alongside each other as if they are one

graph. q2 is the continuation of q1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try `ListLogLinearPlot` or `ListLogLogPlot`

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{q1, q2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{q1, q2}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
p1 = ListPlot[q1, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}]
p2 = ListPlot[q2, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}]
Show[{p2, p1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `ListPlot[{q1, q2}, PlotRange -> All]`.